# How to install Android studio command line tools only on Ubuntu

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, flutter, ubuntu

The major android studio crashes my poor system. Any idea how to install the command line tools on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developer.android.com/studio#downloads
Scroll down to `Command line tools only`

Comment: Yes, I downloaded it but somehow can't figure out how to run it. Any idea how to run it?

Comment: What do you mean by "run"? Do you want to build the app, or you want to launch an emulator? Or something else?

Comment: Yes, launch an emulator.

Comment: check out [this article](https://medium.com/@vsburnett/how-to-set-up-an-android-emulator-in-windows-10-e0a3284b5f94). It's for windows, but the tools are the same